Удаление номенклатуры 1С:Управление нашей фирмой
Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой обработки ответа при запросе на удаление номенкратуры в 1С:Управление нашей фирмой через OData
Вот мой код:
def delete(entity, guid):
    """
    Function to delete a specific entity by its GUID.

    :param entity: Name of the entity
    :param guid: GUID of the entity
    """
    url = f'''http://localhost/mc/odata/standard.odata/{entity}(guid'{guid}')'''
    headers = dict(Accept='application/json')
    response = requests.delete(url, auth=(username, password), headers=headers)
    print(response)
    print(response.status_code)
    try:
        json_response = response.json()
    except:
        raise Exception(response.text)
    if 'odata.error' in json_response:
        raise Exception(json_response['odata.error']['message']['value'])
    
delete(entity='Catalog_Номенклатура', guid='0717035b-480b-11ef-a302-00155d550200')

В других запросах (создание/редактирование) при успешном выполнении запроса возвращается статус 200, а тут 204, но номенклатура при этом удаляется. Есть вариант как обработать ответ, чтобы на 100% удостовериться в том, что объект был удален? Потому что 204 выглядит как-то нездорово

204 No Content — сервер успешно обработал запрос, но в ответе были переданы только заголовки без тела сообщения

это сообщение не является ответом на вопрос. удалите его, и оформите в виде комментария к вопросу. (или добавьте в тело вопроса - вы можете его редактировать).

Этот ответ является ответом на вопрос, 204 ответ означает, что операция совершена успешно и объект удален, просто ответ не несет в себе контекста, он просто пустой

перечитайте свой вопрос еще раз. и свой "ответ".

Все логично, вопрос звучит так "Есть вариант как обработать ответ, чтобы на 100% удостовериться в том, что объект был удален?" В ответе сказано, что 204 ответ говорит об успешном завершении операции, значит объект удален

как раз все не логично - в вашем "ответе" нет варианта обработки ответа сервера. по большому счету, ваш вопрос вызван проблемой, которая таковой не является, поэтому его вообще можно удалить.

Делай что хочешь
